# I did not collect input text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var get=document.getElementById("nameholder").value;
var submit=document.getElementById("submit");

submit.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(get);
});
```

Comment: You're collecting the input value when the page first loads, not when the user clicks the button. Move the `get` assignment into the function.

Comment: `var get=document.getElementById("nameholder").value;` is run before the user can input anything ... `var get` remains unchanged - also, your form is likely to `submit` and load a new page (or reload the current one, depending on your form element, and that console.log may never happen

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var get = document.getElementById("nameholder").value;
  console.log(get);
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id="nameholder" />
<input type='submit' id="submit" />
```